# How to create a coordinate pair

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas, shapely

Have a list of coordinate pairs based on the provided longitudes and latitudes and I want to store the list in a variable coordpairs.

I try using the code below. When I checked the coordinate pair I only get the value for the longitude.

```
for x in range(len(longitudes)):
    longitudes[x]
    
for y in range(len(latitudes)):
    latitudes[y]
    
    coordpairs = (longitudes[x], latitudes[y])
    print(coordpairs)
```

I have about 20 latlon point that I want to pass to a coordinate pair and then use the coordinate pair to create a polygon using this code: poly = Polygon(coordpairs)

Comment: `list(zip(longitudes, latitudes))` I think you want zip

Comment: I see that this is tagged **geopandas**. There's an easy way to do that in geopandas here: https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to your current indentation, coordpairs is only seeing the last value of longitudes each time it loops through *y*.

If you would like to use loops, you could do something like this (assuming your *longitudes* and *latitudes* lists are the same length)

```py
coordpairs = []
for coord_num in range(len(longitudes)):
    coord_pair = [longitudes[coord_num], latitudes[coord_num]]
    coordpairs.append(coord_pair)
```

If you want to combine each item in *longitudes* with each item in *latitudes* without using loops, you can use

```py
list(zip(longitudes, latitudes))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It work perfectly.

Comment: Great, I’m glad to hear that! Please accept the answer if you wouldn’t mind! :)